# Selecting the most recent date on a joined table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I cannot figure out how to create a sub-query to select only the latest date of the grouped by value `sys_loc_code`. Two tables E and R joined on `sys_sample_code`. I want to to the distinct value for the `sys_loc_code` field. I want this to be the data from the row that contains the latest date in it's `sample_date` field.

The code I have so far is:

```
SELECT E.sample_date, E.sys_loc_code, R.sys_sample_code, R.chemical_name, R.result_value, R.detect, R.LabSampType
FROM GMP.GMP_Sample_Results AS R
INNER JOIN GMP.GMP_Sample_Events AS E ON R.sys_sample_code = E.sys_sample_code
WHERE (R.chemical_name = N'Tetrachloroethene') and E.sample_date > '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000'
ORDER BY sys_loc_code, sample_date desc
```

Please see image for desired results. Desired results are in yellow.

[image]

I have tried `MAX`, `DISTINCT`, multiple joins, `MAX DISTINCT`, `GROUP BY` and countless others. Can someone please suggest the code I need to get the results I desire. Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried SELECT TOP 1 [fields]?
(Replace [fields] with your field names)

Comment: Your results don't show the column names. But assuming the "CTM" results are the location, how come you don't want a row for "CTM12D"?

Comment: For future reference if you could avoid using images, instead use formatted text, or for bonus point provide the DDL/DML statements to create sample data.

Comment: @Dale K The result to be selected for CTM12D is off the screen. sys-loc_code is column 3, sys_sample_code is column 4. I will format tables better next time. Will goodle what the heck DDL/DML statements are.

Comment: I did try that but only got one record, the latest sample_date for all records.I am not sure how to get the latest same_date for EACH sys_loc_code @The Grand J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `ROW_NUMBER` and `PARTITION BY` the column you want to be unique and `ORDER BY` the column you want the most recent of, and then take only those results where the row number is 1, you should get what you want.

```
SELECT sample_date, sys_loc_code, sys_sample_code, chemical_name, result_value, detect, LabSampType
FROM (
    SELECT E.sample_date, E.sys_loc_code, R.sys_sample_code, R.chemical_name, R.result_value, R.detect, R.LabSampType
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY E.sys_loc_code ORDER BY sample_date DESC) RN
    FROM GMP.GMP_Sample_Results AS R
    INNER JOIN GMP.GMP_Sample_Events AS E ON R.sys_sample_code = E.sys_sample_code
    WHERE (R.chemical_name = N'Tetrachloroethene') AND E.sample_date > '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000'
) X
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY sys_loc_code, sample_date DESC;
```

Comment: A few issues with the code on my end:

    First line, all the fields from the GMP_Sample_Results table are showing up as invalid field names They are not, and table names are correct.

    All the fields after this row are displaying the error message: "The multipart indentifier <field> could not be bound"

    ROW_NUMBER(  : throws error: "Incorrect syntax near ")" expecting EXCEPT OR UNION

    Also errors at  'WHERE' : "Incorrect syntax near "WHERE" and  at: ') X':  "Incorrect syntax near ")"

Comment: @Bonneroo there was a missing comma before the row_number column which I have now fixed. I suspect the invalid columns names are because you haven't removed the aliases from the outer query? Note the inner query has `E.sample_date` but the outer query has only `sample_date`

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used to get the results I wanted.

```
SELECT R.*, E.sample_date
FROM GMP.GMP_Sample_Results AS R
INNER JOIN GMP.GMP_Sample_Events AS E ON R.sys_sample_code = E.sys_sample_code
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT sys_loc_code, MAX(sample_date) AS MAX_DATE
    FROM GMP.GMP_Sample_Events
    GROUP BY sys_loc_code
) AS MD ON E.sys_loc_code = MD.sys_loc_code AND E.sample_date = MD.MAX_DATE
WHERE (R.chemical_name = 'Tetrachloroethene') AND (E.sample_date > '2016-01-01-00:00:00.000')  
ORDER BY E.sys_loc_code
```

I am intrigued by the TOP 1 and PARTITION solutions also, if anyone would care to explain how I can successfully get these to work. There is always more than 1 way to skin a cat. As a beginner, the more tools I have in my memory box the better I will be at my job. Thanks to all that have helped so far. @Dale K , if you can find a solution to the errors in the comments section, I will mark your's as answered as well.